# Filter ol.format.filter.equalTo() by feature ID?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

If it possible to create a filter by feature-ids in OL4 like

```
ol.format.filter.equalTo(<fid>,<value>).
```

In OL2 there is `new OpenLayers.Filter.FeatureId({})` in OL4 I have not found anything compareable.